# Convert WPA_passphrase output to /etc/network/interface

Tags: shell-script, awk, text-formatting

This is primarily a formatting problem which I haven't been able to solve well.

I want to create a bash function or script which converts output from wpa-passphrase to a format that can be used by /etc/network/interfaces.

**Example WPA-Supplicant**

```
wpa_passphrase ssid password
```

**Produces the following output**

```
network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    #psk="passphrase"
    psk=ccb290fd4fe6b22935cbae31449e050edd02ad44627b16ce0151668f5f53c01b
}
```

I need to convert that output to a format which can be used by /etc/network/interfaces

**Example of the /etc/network/interface output format:**

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid MYSSID
        wpa-psk ccb290fd4fe6b22935cbae31449e050edd02ad44627b16ce0151668f5f53c01b
```

My first crude solution was to use:

```
wpa_passphrase MYSSID PASSWORD |grep -E 'ssid|psk' |grep -v "#psk" |cut -d '=' -f 2
```

Which gives me:

```
MYSSID
ccb290fd4fe6b22935cbae31449e050edd02ad44627b16ce0151668f5f53c01b
```

but I don't know how to get each of those lines into their proper place in the /etc/network/interfaces format

**UPDATE: With my current solution**

After further attempts I managed to get it to work with this:

```
while read line
do
        echo "auto wlp3s0"
        echo "iface wlp3s0 inet dhcp"           
        echo -e "\t wpa-ssid $line"
done < <(sudo wpa_passphrase $1 $2 |grep -E 'ssid' |cut -d '=' -f 2)

while read line
do
        echo -e "\t wpa-psk $line"
done < <(sudo wpa_passphrase $1 $2 |grep -E 'psk' |grep -v "#psk" |cut -d '=' -f 2)
```

My solution gives the output I need, but it does not seem efficient and I would still like to see other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a function as below and use `awk` to format the output as you want:

```
generate() {
sudo wpa_passphrase "$1" "$2" | 
awk -F= 'BEGIN      { print "auto wlan0\n" "iface wlan0 inet dhcp" }
         /ssid/     { print "", "wpa-ssid", $2 }
         /[^#]psk=/ { print "", "wpa-psk" , $2 }' OFS='\t'
}
```

Then call `generate "my SSID" "PASSWORD"`.

Output would be:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid        "my SSID"
        wpa-psk ccb290fd4fe6b22935cbae31449e050edd02ad44627b16ce0151668f5f53c01b
```